# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/SOAPException while Generating Java Class from WSDL

Tags: java, gradle, ant, wsdl2java

I have a spring boot application with Gradle where I am trying to generate the Java classes from some WSDL file.
I am working with Java 1.8 and Gradle 6.7.

I have defined a Gradle task generateWsdlClasses and is working perfectly fine if I am executing this task individually but when I am building the project with "gardle build" I am getting some very unexpected error.

Looked into some suggestion like including "javax.xml.soap-api" dependency which is irrelevant since I am working with Java8 only but even that didn't work out for me.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    axisGenAntTask
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'){
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    
    //AXIS-ANT Dependencies
    axisGenAntTask "org.apache.axis:axis-ant:1.4",
            "org.apache.axis:axis:1.4",
            "org.apache.axis:axis-jaxrpc:1.4",
            "axis:axis-wsdl4j:1.5.1",
            "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3",
            "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1",
            "commons-discovery:commons-discovery:0.2"
}

//GEN WSDL task
task generateWsdlClasses(){
    ant.echo(message:"Generating java classes from WSDL")
    ant.taskdef(
            name: "genClassesFromWSDL",
            classname: "org.apache.axis.tools.ant.wsdl.Wsdl2javaAntTask",
            classpath: configurations.axisGenAntTask.asPath
    )
    ant.genClassesFromWSDL(url:"src/main/resources/wsdl/EntitlementService.wsdl",output:"src/main/java",deployscope:"session",serverSide:"false",
            noWrapped:"true",skeletonDeploy:"false",verbose:"true",typeMappingVersion:"1.2",testcase:"no") {
        mapping(namespace: "urn:TestNS:XML:Jbo/01:Types", package: "com.mypackage.runtime")

    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**Error Log**

```
> Configure project :
[ant:echo] Generating Classes for use with WSDL
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/SOAPException
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.apache.axis.encoding.DefaultTypeMappingImpl.initMappings(DefaultTypeMappingImpl.java:119)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.apache.axis.encoding.DefaultTypeMappingImpl.<init>(DefaultTypeMappingImpl.java:91)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.apache.axis.encoding.DefaultTypeMappingImpl.getSingletonDelegate(DefaultTypeMappingImpl.java
:85)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingRegistryImpl.<init>(TypeMappingRegistryImpl.java:155)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingRegistryImpl.<init>(TypeMappingRegistryImpl.java:149)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.Emitter.<init>(Emitter.java:144)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.apache.axis.tools.ant.wsdl.Wsdl2javaAntTask.createEmitter(Wsdl2javaAntTask.java:615)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.apache.axis.tools.ant.wsdl.Wsdl2javaAntTask.execute(Wsdl2javaAntTask.java:211)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor87.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.
java:43)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at groovy.util.AntBuilder.performTask(AntBuilder.java:333)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted(AntBuilder.java:278)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.nodeCompleted(BasicAntBuilder.java:80)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:151)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(AntBuilder.java:213)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(BasicAntBuilder.java:107)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:64)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:43)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:135)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at 
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:421)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureSelf(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.configure(AbstractTask.java:599)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.configure(DefaultTask.java:307)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.task(DefaultProject.java:1264)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.
java:43)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject
.java:484)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:196)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.jav
a:98)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(M
ixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:34)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:134)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:163
)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.invokeMethod(BasicScript.java:83)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:71)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:176)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at build_5d316is2u43smhcq3uxe8jb0p.run(C:\ems\build.gradle:42)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScript
RunnerFactory.java:91)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScrip
tPluginFactory.java:133)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFa
ctory.java:136)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner
.java:29)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner
.java:26)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner
.java:75)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner
.java:68)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.j
ava:153)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.j
ava:68)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:
56)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationE
xecutor.java:71)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedB
uildOperationWrapper.java:45)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.j
ava:71)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.ja
va:62)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplica
tionContext.java:43)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutab
leState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:248)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(De
faultProjectStateRegistry.java:275)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState
(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:247)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProje
ctEvaluator.java:35)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(Lifecycl
eProjectEvaluator.java:100)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutab
leState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:248)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectL
ock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:308)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:178)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(Def
aultProjectStateRegistry.java:308)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(De
faultProjectStateRegistry.java:289)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState
(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:247)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectE
valuator.java:91)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner
.java:29)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner
.java:26)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner
.java:75)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner
.java:68)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.j
ava:153)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.j
ava:68)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:
56)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationE
xecutor.java:71)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedB
uildOperationWrapper.java:45)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.j
ava:71)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.ja
va:63)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:710)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:145)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:36)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:6
2)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:46
)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingPr
ojectsPreparer.java:57)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationF
iringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner
.java:29)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner
.java:26)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner
.java:75)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner
.java:68)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.j
ava:153)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.j
ava:68)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:
56)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationE
xecutor.java:71)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedB
uildOperationWrapper.java:45)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.j
ava:71)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiri
ngProjectsPreparer.java:40)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareProjects(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:228)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:
165)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:126)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:72)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:67)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:178)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:
31)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildAc
tionRunner.java:63)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner
.java:32)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingB
uildActionRunner.java:67)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingB
uildActionRunner.java:41)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildAct
ionRunner.java:49)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildAct
ionRunner.java:44)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(
DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(
DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner
.java:75)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner
.java:68)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.j
ava:153)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.j
ava:68)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java
:62)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperation
Executor.java:76)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(Unmanaged
BuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.
java:76)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildAction
Runner.java:44)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecu
ter.java:54)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:87)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:
53)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:
29)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeSc
opeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:49)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecy
cleBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecy
cleBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildAction
Executer.java:104)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildAction
Executer.java:55)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildAc
tionExecuter.java:64)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildAc
tionExecuter.java:37)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(S
essionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionSco
peLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionSco
peLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildAc
tionExecuter.java:36)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildAc
tionExecuter.java:25)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsVali
datingActionExecuter.java:59)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsVali
datingActionExecuter.java:31)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailur
eReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailur
eReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecut
er.java:47)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecut
er.java:31)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java
:104)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:
39)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java
:104)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.jav
a:29)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java
:104)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingle
UsedDaemon.java:35)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java
:104)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java
:104)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java
:104)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java
:104)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironme
nt.java:84)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java
:104)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWith
Busy.java:52)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.ja
va:64)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.jav
a:56)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1383)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1338)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1093)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
[ant:genClassesFromWSDL]        ... 198 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency :

For `gradle` : `implementation 'javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api:1.4.0'`

For `maven` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```